# Evaluating Safety of Sending Emails via Python

Tags: python, email, security, smtp

I want to send emails in a production environment using Python. Since I don't have extensive security and networking experience, I want to ensure that sending the email programmatically is being done safely.

Hence, I need to know if the following code that I plan on using is safe and what concerns I should be considering when doing this via Python:

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587
smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"
sender_email = "@hotmail.com"
receiver_email = "@hotmail.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter:")
message = """\
Subject: Hi there

This message is sent from Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Comment: I would use the `getpass` function in the [getpass module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) for password entry rather than `input`.